# plot the mean and std after looping over multiple densities

Tags: python, statistics

I have this function

```
def plot_density(X, bandwidth, ax):

    x_axis = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)
    dens_list = []
    for x in X:
        kernel = stats.norm(x, bandwidth).pdf(x_axis)
        dens_list.append(kernel)

    ax.set_xlim(0,1)

    density = np.mean(density_list, axis = 0)

    ax.plot(x_axis, density ,color = 'red')
    sns.rugplot(X)
```

I want to loop `for i in range (4):` 
then get mean and std of the repeated densities and plot the mean and std how can I do that

Comment: i think there is error in your code,what is `x` and `xx`

Comment: yes but how can I loop!! and calculate the mean and plot?

Comment: get rid of plot part of the function and just `return density ,x_axis` and then you can for loop the function with `plt.plot(x_axis,density)`

Comment: it didn't work .. is there other suggestions

Comment: can you show me the code you have written